# On injections and surjections

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $f:N^2 \rightarrow N$ be defined by $f(x, y) = x^3 + y^3$.

I can tell that $f$ is not injective, but would it be surjective?

Any intuitive explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $\Bbb N=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$? If so, can $f(x,y)=3$?

Comment: @cxx Apart from $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

Comment: Oops. My mistake.

Comment: It wouldn't be surjective, in fact even within $10$ it misses so many numbers. The sum can't be any of $3,4,5,6,7$, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the values for (0,0), (0,1), (1,1), (1,2), (2,2). None of them is 3 (for example).

If either $n_k$ in $(n_1 , n_2)$ is bigger than 2, you'll get values bigger than you got by calculating those, so none of them can be 3 either.

If you have $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1,2,...\}$, the proof is even easier.